# How can I enable a TINYMCE rich text editor in the admin interface?

Tags: categories, wp-admin, tinymce, editor, plugin-tinymce

I'd like to add some text above my category archives, and I'd like to use the built-in Wordpress TinyMCE editor to do it. I've seen some plugins like `black-studio-tinymce-widget` which does a nice job of adding rich text to a widget, but I'd like to set up TinyMce to be used in the description area of the Edit Category page.

Is there a plugin to do this or how would I set up Wordpress to allow this?

[screenshot-with-shadow.png http://img140.imageshack.us/img140/4526/screenshotwithshadow.png](http://img140.imageshack.us/img140/4526/screenshotwithshadow.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this looks ot be what you are after http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rich-text-tags/

Answer (score 3):

`wp_editor()`  outputs the textarea(html codes),
so, maybe you dont need to use that in functions.php, but use inside the page's source.
(where that textarea is generated, for example like this:

```
<div class="blabla>
  <form action="" method="POST">
  <?php wp_editor( 'Hi,its content' , 'desired_id_of_textarea', $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'your_desired_name_for_$POST') ); ?> 
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

note: it may wont work for `add_option` function..